# Get Data with PHP

Tags: php, html

(function(e,t){function n(t,n){var i,s,o,u=t.nodeName.toLowerCase();return"area"===u?(i=t.parentNode,s=i.name,!t.href||!s||i.nodeName.toLowerCase()!=="map"?!1:(o=e("img[usemap=#"+s+"]")[0],!!o&&r(o))):(/input|select|textarea|button|object/.test(u)?!t.disabled:"a"===u?t.href||n:n)&&r(t)}function r(t){return e.expr.filters.visible(t)&&!e(t).parents().andSelf().filter(function(){return e.css(this,"visibility")==="hidden"}).length}var i=0,s=/^ui-id-\d+$/;e.ui=e.ui||{};if(e.ui.version)return;e.extend(e.ui,{version:"1.9.2",keyCode:{BACKSPACE:8,COMMA:188,DELETE:46,DOWN:40,END:35,ENTER:13,ESCAPE:27,HOME:36,LEFT:37,NUMPAD_ADD:107,NUMPAD_DECIMAL:110,NUMPAD_DIVIDE:111,NUMPAD_ENTER:108,NUMPAD_MULTIPLY:106,NUMPAD_SUBTRACT:109,PAGE_DOWN:34,PAGE_UP:33,PERIOD:190,RIGHT:39,SPACE:32,TAB:9,UP:38}}),e.fn.extend({_focus:e.fn.focus,focus:function(t,n){return typeof t=="number"?this.each(function(){var r=this;setTimeout(function(){e(r).focus(),n&&n.call(r)},t)}):this._focus.apply(this,arguments)},scrollParent:function(){var t;return e.ui.ie&&/(static|relative)/.test(this.css("position"))||/absolute/.test(this.css("position"))?t=this.parents().filter(function(){return/(relative|absolute|fixed)/.test(e.css(this,"position"))&&/(auto|scroll)/.test(e.css(this,"overflow")+e.css(this,"overflow-y")+e.css(this,"overflow-x"))}).eq(0):t=this.parents().filter(function(){return/(auto|scroll)/.test(e.css(this,"overflow")+e.css(this,"overflow-y")+e.css(this,"overflow-x"))}).eq(0),/fixed/.test(this.css("position"))||!t.length?e(document):t},zIndex:function(n){if(n!==t)return this.css("zIndex",n);if(this.length){var r=e(this[0]),i,s;while(r.length&&r[0]!==document){i=r.css("position");if(i==="absolute"||i==="relative"||i==="fixed"){s=parseInt(r.css("zIndex"),10);if(!isNaN(s)&&s!==0)return s}r=r.parent()}}return 0},uniqueId:function(){return this.each(function(){this.id||(this.id="ui-id-"+(1+i))})},removeUniqueId:function(){return this.each(function(){s.test(this.id)&&e(this).removeAttr("id")})}}),e.extend(e.expr[":"],{data:e.expr.createPseudo?e.expr.createPseudo(function(t){return function(n){return!!e.data(n,t)}}):function(t,n,r){return!!e.data(t,r[3])},focusable:function(t){return n(t,!isNaN(e.attr(t,"tabindex")))},tabbable:function(t){var r=e.attr(t,"tabindex"),i=isNaN(r);return(i||r>=0)&&n(t,!i)}}),e(function(){var t=document.body,n=t.appendChild(n=document.createElement("div"));n.offsetHeight,e.extend(n.style,{minHeight:"100px",height:"auto",padding:0,borderWidth:0}),e.support.minHeight=n.offsetHeight===100,e.support.selectstart="onselectstart"in n,t.removeChild(n).style.display="none"}),e("").outerWidth(1).jquery||e.each(["Width","Height"],function(n,r){function i(t,n,r,i){return e.each(s,function(){n-=parseFloat(e.css(t,"padding"+this))||0,r&&(n-=parseFloat(e.css(t,"border"+this+"Width"))||0),i&&(n-=parseFloat(e.css(t,"margin"+this))||0)}),n}var s=r==="Width"?["Left","Right"]:["Top","Bottom"],o=r.toLowerCase(),u={innerWidth:e.fn.innerWidth,innerHeight:e.fn.innerHeight,outerWidth:e.fn.outerWidth,outerHeight:e.fn.outerHeight};e.fn["inner"+r]=function(n){return n===t?u["inner"+r].call(this):this.each(function(){e(this).css(o,i(this,n)+"px")})},e.fn["outer"+r]=function(t,n){return typeof t!="number"?u["outer"+r].call(this,t):this.each(function(){e(this).css(o,i(this,t,!0,n)+"px")})}}),e("").data("a-b","a").removeData("a-b").data("a-b")&&(e.fn.removeData=function(t){return function(n){return arguments.length?t.call(this,e.camelCase(n)):t.call(this)}}(e.fn.removeData)),function(){var t=/msie ([\w.]+)/.exec(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase())||[];e.ui.ie=t.length?!0:!1,e.ui.ie6=parseFloat(t[1],10)===6}(),e.fn.extend({disableSelection:function(){return this.bind((e.support.selectstart?"selectstart":"mousedown")+".ui-disableSelection",function(e){e.preventDefault()})},enableSelection:function(){return this.unbind(".ui-disableSelection")}}),e.extend(e.ui,{plugin:{add:function(t,n,r){var i,s=e.ui[t].prototype;for(i in r)s.plugins[i]=s.plugins[i]||[],s.plugins[i].push([n,r[i]])},call:function(e,t,n){var r,i=e.plugins[t];if(!i||!e.element[0].parentNode||e.element[0].parentNode.nodeType===11)return;for(r=0;r0?!0:(t[r]=1,i=t[r]>0,t[r]=0,i)},isOverAxis:function(e,t,n){return e>t&&e",options:{disabled:!1,create:null},_createWidget:function(t,r){r=e(r||this.defaultElement||this)[0],this.element=e(r),this.uuid=n++,this.eventNamespace="."+this.widgetName+this.uuid,this.options=e.widget.extend({},this.options,this._getCreateOptions(),t),this.bindings=e(),this.hoverable=e(),this.focusable=e(),r!==this&&(e.data(r,this.widgetName,this),e.data(r,this.widgetFullName,this),this._on(!0,this.element,{remove:function(e){e.target===r&&this.destroy()}}),this.document=e(r.style?r.ownerDocument:r.document||r),this.window=e(this.document[0].defaultView||this.document[0].parentWindow)),this._create(),this._trigger("create",null,this._getCreateEventData()),this._init()},_getCreateOptions:e.noop,_getCreateEventData:e.noop,_create:e.noop,_init:e.noop,destroy:function(){this._destroy(),this.element.unbind(this.eventNamespace).removeData(this.widgetName).removeData(this.widgetFullName).removeData(e.camelCase(this.widgetFullName)),this.widget().unbind(this.eventNamespace).removeAttr("aria-disabled").removeClass(this.widgetFullName+"-disabled "+"ui-state-disabled"),this.bindings.unbind(this.eventNamespace),this.hoverable.removeClass("ui-state-hover"),this.focusable.removeClass("ui-state-focus")},_destroy:e.noop,widget:function(){return this.element},option:function(n,r){var i=n,s,o,u;if(arguments.length===0)return e.widget.extend({},this.options);if(typeof n=="string"){i={},s=n.split("."),n=s.shift();if(s.length){o=i[n]=e.widget.extend({},this.options[n]);for(u=0;ut:u!==t&&r[u]?ru:r.queue(function(n){e(this)t,s&&s.call(r[0]),n()})}}),e.uiBackCompat!==!1&&(e.Widget.prototype._getCreateOptions=function(){return e.metadata&&e.metadata.get(this.element[0])[this.widgetName]})})(jQuery);(function(e,t){var n=!1;e(document).mouseup(function(e){n=!1}),e.widget("ui.mouse",{version:"1.9.2",options:{cancel:"input,textarea,button,select,option",distance:1,delay:0},_mouseInit:function(){var t=this;this.element.bind("mousedown."+this.widgetName,function(e){return t._mouseDown(e)}).bind("click."+this.widgetName,function(n){if(!0===e.data(n.target,t.widgetName+".preventClickEvent"))return e.removeData(n.target,t.widgetName+".preventClickEvent"),n.stopImmediatePropagation(),!1}),this.started=!1},_mouseDestroy:function(){this.element.unbind("."+this.widgetName),this._mouseMoveDelegate&&e(document).unbind("mousemove."+this.widgetName,this._mouseMoveDelegate).unbind("mouseup."+this.widgetName,this._mouseUpDelegate)},_mouseDown:function(t){if(n)return;this._mouseStarted&&this._mouseUp(t),this._mouseDownEvent=t;var r=this,i=t.which===1,s=typeof this.options.cancel=="string"&&t.target.nodeName?e(t.target).closest(this.options.cancel).length:!1;if(!i||s||!this._mouseCapture(t))return!0;this.mouseDelayMet=!this.options.delay,this.mouseDelayMet||(this._mouseDelayTimer=setTimeout(function(){r.mouseDelayMet=!0},this.options.delay));if(this._mouseDistanceMet(t)&&this._mouseDelayMet(t)){this._mouseStarted=this._mouseStart(t)!==!1;if(!this._mouseStarted)return t.preventDefault(),!0}return!0===e.data(t.target,this.widgetName+".preventClickEvent")&&e.removeData(t.target,this.widgetName+".preventClickEvent"),this._mouseMoveDelegate=function(e){return r._mouseMove(e)},this._mouseUpDelegate=function(e){return r._mouseUp(e)},e(document).bind("mousemove."+this.widgetName,this._mouseMoveDelegate).bind("mouseup."+this.widgetName,this._mouseUpDelegate),t.preventDefault(),n=!0,!0},_mouseMove:function(t){return!e.ui.ie||document.documentMode>=9||!!t.button?this._mouseStarted?(this._mouseDrag(t),t.preventDefault()):(this._mouseDistanceMet(t)&&this._mouseDelayMet(t)&&(this._mouseStarted=this._mouseStart(this._mouseDownEvent,t)!==!1,this._mouseStarted?this._mouseDrag(t):this._mouseUp(t)),!this._mouseStarted):this._mouseUp(t)},_mouseUp:function(t){return e(document).unbind("mousemove."+this.widgetName,this._mouseMoveDelegate).unbind("mouseup."+this.widgetName,this._mouseUpDelegate),this._mouseStarted&&(this._mouseStarted=!1,t.target===this._mouseDownEvent.target&&e.data(t.target,this.widgetName+".preventClickEvent",!0),this._mouseStop(t)),!1},_mouseDistanceMet:function(e){return Math.max(Math.abs(this._mouseDownEvent.pageX-e.pageX),Math.abs(this._mouseDownEvent.pageY-e.pageY))>=this.options.distance},_mouseDelayMet:function(e){return this.mouseDelayMet},_mouseStart:function(e){},_mouseDrag:function(e){},_mouseStop:function(e){},_mouseCapture:function(e){return!0}})})(jQuery);(function(e,t){function n(e,t,n){return[parseInt(e[0],10)*(h.test(e[0])?t/100:1),parseInt(e[1],10)*(h.test(e[1])?n/100:1)]}function r(t,n){return parseInt(e.css(t,n),10)||0}e.ui=e.ui||{};var i,s=Math.max,o=Math.abs,u=Math.round,a=/left|center|right/,f=/top|center|bottom/,l=/[+-]\d+%?/,c=/^\w+/,h=/%$/,p=e.fn.position;e.position={scrollbarWidth:function(){if(i!==t)return i;var n,r,s=e(""),o=s.children()[0];return e("body").append(s),n=o.offsetWidth,s.css("overflow","scroll"),r=o.offsetWidth,n===r&&(r=s[0].clientWidth),s.remove(),i=n-r},getScrollInfo:function(t){var n=t.isWindow?"":t.element.css("overflow-x"),r=t.isWindow?"":t.element.css("overflow-y"),i=n==="scroll"||n==="auto"&&t.widthr}),e.fn.bgiframe&&l.bgiframe(),t.using&&(f=function(e){var n=v.left-C.left,r=n+h-c,i=v.top-C.top,u=i+d-p,a={target:{element:g,left:v.left,top:v.top,width:h,height:d},element:{element:l,left:C.left,top:C.top,width:c,height:p},horizontal:r<0?"left":n>0?"right":"center",vertical:u<0?"top":i>0?"bottom":"middle"};hs(o(i),o(u))?a.important="horizontal":a.important="vertical",t.using.call(this,e,a)}),l.offset(e.extend(C,{using:f}))})},e.ui.position={fit:{left:function(e,t){var n=t.within,r=n.isWindow?n.scrollLeft:n.offset.left,i=n.width,o=e.left-t.collisionPosition.marginLeft,u=r-o,a=o+t.collisionWidth-i-r,f;t.collisionWidth>i?u>0&&a<=0?(f=e.left+u+t.collisionWidth-i-r,e.left+=u-f):a>0&&u<=0?e.left=r:u>a?e.left=r+i-t.collisionWidth:e.left=r:u>0?e.left+=u:a>0?e.left-=a:e.left=s(e.left-o,e.left)},top:function(e,t){var n=t.within,r=n.isWindow?n.scrollTop:n.offset.top,i=t.within.height,o=e.top-t.collisionPosition.marginTop,u=r-o,a=o+t.collisionHeight-i-r,f;t.collisionHeight>i?u>0&&a<=0?(f=e.top+u+t.collisionHeight-i-r,e.top+=u-f):a>0&&u<=0?e.top=r:u>a?e.top=r+i-t.collisionHeight:e.top=r:u>0?e.top+=u:a>0?e.top-=a:e.top=s(e.top-o,e.top)}},flip:{left:function(e,t){var n=t.within,r=n.offset.left+n.scrollLeft,i=n.width,s=n.isWindow?n.scrollLeft:n.offset.left,u=e.left-t.collisionPosition.marginLeft,a=u-s,f=u+t.collisionWidth-i-s,l=t.my[0]==="left"?-t.elemWidth:t.my[0]==="right"?t.elemWidth:0,c=t.at[0]==="left"?t.targetWidth:t.at[0]==="right"?-t.targetWidth:0,h=-2*t.offset[0],p,d;if(a<0){p=e.left+l+c+h+t.collisionWidth-i-r;if(p<0||p0){d=e.left-t.collisionPosition.marginLeft+l+c+h-s;if(d>0||o(d)a&&(v<0||v0&&(d=e.top-t.collisionPosition.marginTop+c+h+p-s,e.top+c+h+p>f&&(d>0||o(d)10&&i<11,t.innerHTML="",n.removeChild(t)}(),e.uiBackCompat!==!1&&function(e){var n=e.fn.position;e.fn.position=function(r){if(!r||!r.offset)return n.call(this,r);var i=r.offset.split(" "),s=r.at.split(" ");return i.length===1&&(i[1]=i[0]),/^\d/.test(i[0])&&(i[0]="+"+i[0]),/^\d/.test(i[1])&&(i[1]="+"+i[1]),s.length===1&&(/left|center|right/.test(s[0])?s[1]="center":(s[1]=s[0],s[0]="center")),n.call(this,e.extend(r,{at:s[0]+i[0]+" "+s[1]+i[1],offset:t}))}}(jQuery)})(jQuery);(function(e,t){var n=0;e.widget("ui.autocomplete",{version:"1.9.2",defaultElement:"",options:{appendTo:"body",autoFocus:!1,delay:300,minLength:1,position:{my:"left top",at:"left bottom",collision:"none"},source:null,change:null,close:null,focus:null,open:null,response:null,search:null,select:null},pending:0,_create:function(){var t,n,r;this.isMultiLine=this._isMultiLine(),this.valueMethod=this.element[this.element.is("input,textarea")?"val":"text"],this.isNewMenu=!0,this.element.addClass("ui-autocomplete-input").attr("autocomplete","off"),this._on(this.element,{keydown:function(i){if(this.element.prop("readOnly")){t=!0,r=!0,n=!0;return}t=!1,r=!1,n=!1;var s=e.ui.keyCode;switch(i.keyCode){case s.PAGE_UP:t=!0,this._move("previousPage",i);break;case s.PAGE_DOWN:t=!0,this._move("nextPage",i);break;case s.UP:t=!0,this._keyEvent("previous",i);break;case s.DOWN:t=!0,this._keyEvent("next",i);break;case s.ENTER:case s.NUMPAD_ENTER:this.menu.active&&(t=!0,i.preventDefault(),this.menu.select(i));break;case s.TAB:this.menu.active&&this.menu.select(i);break;case s.ESCAPE:this.menu.element.is(":visible")&&(this._value(this.term),this.close(i),i.preventDefault());break;default:n=!0,this._searchTimeout(i)}},keypress:function(r){if(t){t=!1,r.preventDefault();return}if(n)return;var i=e.ui.keyCode;switch(r.keyCode){case i.PAGE_UP:this._move("previousPage",r);break;case i.PAGE_DOWN:this._move("nextPage",r);break;case i.UP:this._keyEvent("previous",r);break;case i.DOWN:this._keyEvent("next",r)}},input:function(e){if(r){r=!1,e.preventDefault();return}this._searchTimeout(e)},focus:function(){this.selectedItem=null,this.previous=this._value()},blur:function(e){if(this.cancelBlur){delete this.cancelBlur;return}clearTimeout(this.searching),this.close(e),this._change(e)}}),this._initSource(),this.menu=e("").addClass("ui-autocomplete").appendTo(this.document.find(this.options.appendTo||"body")[0]).menu({input:e(),role:null}).zIndex(this.element.zIndex()+1).hide().data("menu"),this._on(this.menu.element,{mousedown:function(t){t.preventDefault(),this.cancelBlur=!0,this._delay(function(){delete this.cancelBlur});var n=this.menu.element[0];e(t.target).closest(".ui-menu-item").length||this._delay(function(){var t=this;this.document.one("mousedown",function(r){r.target!==t.element[0]&&r.target!==n&&!e.contains(n,r.target)&&t.close()})})},menufocus:function(t,n){if(this.isNewMenu){this.isNewMenu=!1;if(t.originalEvent&&/^mouse/.test(t.originalEvent.type)){this.menu.blur(),this.document.one("mousemove",function(){e(t.target).trigger(t.originalEvent)});return}}var r=n.item.data("ui-autocomplete-item")||n.item.data("item.autocomplete");!1!==this._trigger("focus",t,{item:r})?t.originalEvent&&/^key/.test(t.originalEvent.type)&&this._value(r.value):this.liveRegion.text(r.value)},menuselect:function(e,t){var n=t.item.data("ui-autocomplete-item")||t.item.data("item.autocomplete"),r=this.previous;this.element[0]!==this.document[0].activeElement&&(this.element.focus(),this.previous=r,this._delay(function(){this.previous=r,this.selectedItem=n})),!1!==this._trigger("select",e,{item:n})&&this._value(n.value),this.term=this._value(),this.close(e),this.selectedItem=n}}),this.liveRegion=e("",{role:"status","aria-live":"polite"}).addClass("ui-helper-hidden-accessible").insertAfter(this.element),e.fn.bgiframe&&this.menu.element.bgiframe(),this._on(this.window,{beforeunload:function()

Comment: Define "not working". What do you expect to see? What are you actually getting? What debugging have you done yourself to isolate the problem?

Comment: Honestly speaking, I do not know why its not working

Comment: @user3173884, you don't need to know *why* it's not working. But you do need to say *what* isn't working. "I get error BLAH." "I expect to see a page that does FOO but instead it does BAR."

Comment: page goes blank! No errors!

Comment: And have you done a `php -l <filename>.php` from the command line to syntax check your files, or looked in the webserver logs to see if there's any errors there... these are very basic checks that every developer should be aware of

Comment: I don't think that `$slide` is a defined variable.  You may want `$slides[0]['slideshow_caption_title']`

Comment: None gave satisfied answer!

Comment: It isn't exactly a satisfactory question either... SO isn't a free debugging service, you're expected to do some basic debugging work yourself before asking other people to give their time and effort for free

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
$output .= $slide['slideshow_caption_title'])) $data .=     '<h1 '.$font_style.'>'.$slide['slideshow_caption_title'].'</h1>';
```

to:

```
$output .= $slide['slideshow_caption_title'];
$output .= '<h1 '.$font_style.'>'.$slide['slideshow_caption_title'].'</h1>';
```

and add:

```
echo $output;
```

after:

```
$output .= "</div><!-- end .relThumb -->\n";
```

Comment: Do you even echo or print `$output`?

Comment: Indeed, good question @user2819389

Comment: I edited my answer, if still not working you'll need to explain more and give us some error codes as I fixed all problems in your last code.

Comment: No, Now Its not blank, But it break whole code! Not working again